# Set to Json : NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Set<Map<String, dynamic>>' has no instance method 'toJson'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have the next code :

`{{id: 1, someFlag: true}, {id: 2, someFlag: true}, {id: 3, someFlag: true}}`

```dart
 final intSets = Set<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
      ids.map((x) => (x as IdModel).toMap()),
 );

 // ! ERROR HERE
 final intSetString = jsonEncode(intSets);
```

I want to know if there isn't a way to convert a json string a Set map ?

Comment: [JSON can represent numbers, booleans, strings, null, arrays (ordered sequences of values), and objects (string-value mappings) made up of these values (or of other arrays and objects). JSON does not natively represent more complex data types like functions, regular expressions, dates, and so on.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/JSON) A "Set" is simply not a data type supported by the JSON standard. You will have to convert the Set to something that is supported by JSON, for example an array (List in dart). `jsonEncode(intSets.toList());`

Answer (score 3):

You can convert a JSON string to a `Set<Map<String, dynamic>>`. Here's an example code snippet:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final jsonString = '[{"id": 1, "someFlag": true}, {"id": 2, "someFlag": true}, {"id": 3, "someFlag": true}]';

  final List<dynamic> jsonList = jsonDecode(jsonString);
  final intSets = jsonList.map((json) => Map<String, dynamic>.from(json)).toSet();
  
  final intSetString = jsonEncode(intSets);
  print(intSetString);
}
```

This code first defines a JSON string that matches the format of the input data you provided. It then uses `jsonDecode` to convert the string to a `List<dynamic>` of JSON objects. Next, it maps each JSON object to a `Map<String, dynamic>`, and then converts the resulting `Iterable` to a `Set` using the `toSet()` method. Finally, it uses `jsonEncode` to convert the `Set` back to a JSON string.

Note that in this code, the keys in the JSON objects are represented as strings, so the resulting `Map`s also have string keys. If you need to use specific data types for the keys or values in the maps, you'll need to perform additional conversions.